# Can we use es6 with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on an angularJS website and i wanna know if we can code in es6 natively (we use babel now) since the web browsers support es6.

Thanks,

Marius

EDIT: i use AngularJS 1.5.8

Comment: be specific with your angular version 1.x or > 2 ?

Comment: Yes you can. https://www.timroes.de/2015/07/29/using-ecmascript-6-es6-with-angularjs-1-x/

Comment: that's not natively, i just wanna know if we can do this without compilation (without babel or other preprocessor)

Comment: Here you go for babel - https://instil.co/2016/09/27/angular-1-es6/ but currently industry transpiling to ES5 in order to support many old browsers like IE etc. thats a bullet proof solution